# Stored Procedures in EF Core 3.0

Tags: .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

How to use stored procedures in EF Core 3.0 ?

I have tried the following

```
var user = await _context.Query<User>().FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.spGeneral_Authenticate").FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var user = await _context.Query<User>().FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.spGeneral_Authenticate").FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var user = await _context.Set<User>().FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.spGeneral_Authenticate").FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var user = await _context.Set<User>().FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.spGeneral_Authenticate").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

EF core translating the SQL in wrong way. I got the translated SQL from log file.

> 2019-09-27 11:21:36.086 +05:30 [Error] Failed executing DbCommand
>   ("30"ms) [Parameters=[""], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"
>   ""SELECT TOP(1) [u].[FullName], [u].[Password], [u].[UserName] FROM (
>       EXECUTE dbo.spGeneral_Authenticate ) AS [u]" 2019-09-27 11:21:36.154 +05:30 [Error] An exception occurred while iterating over
>   the results of a query for context type '"__________Context"'."
>   ""Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax
>   near the keyword 'EXECUTE'. Incorrect syntax near ')'.

**Translated SQL:**

```
SELECT TOP(1) [u].[FullName], [u].[Password], [u].[UserName]
FROM (
    EXECUTE dbo.spGeneral_Authenticate
) AS [u]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax
>   near the keyword 'EXECUTE'. Incorrect syntax near ')'.

For the above error, we should use .ToList() or .ToListAsync() not .FirstOrDefault() or .FirstOrDefaultAsync()

It will work

```
var user = await _context.Set<User>().FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.spTest").ToListAsync();
```

It won't work

```
var user = await _context.Set<User>().FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.spTest").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
/*
Transalated SQL:
SELECT TOP(1) [u].[FullName], [u].[Password], [u].[UserName]
FROM (
    EXECUTE dbo.spTest
) AS [u]
*/
```

Comment: Did you find the way to get only one object with raw sql?

Comment: @Kiran Shahi, .ToList().FirstOrDefault()

Comment: ToList or ToListAsync is not the solution, it gives the same error. Which is not surprising because there is no reason it would behave differently. At my side what is actually run is the following:
SELECT [u].[FullName], [u].[Password], [u].[UserName]
FROM (
    EXECUTE dbo.spTest
) AS [u]
So... exactly the same pb

Comment: @Stephane, it's working as expected, check the fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/XudenD

Comment: the code that fails a copy paste from my code. Actuially, the pb lies in the fast that I have a global query filter setup on this entity. I noticed that it is impossible to have any stored procedure running if what is returned has a global query filter setup, or if it is an entity that inherits from another entity. I left an issue on github about this.

Comment: @Stephane do you have the link to the issue you raised.  I am having the same issue as you.

Comment: @Matt here is it: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18232

Comment: @Kiran Shahi, var user = (await _context.Set<User>().FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.spTest").ToListAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer nails it. Here are my two cents however:

Also, if you want to get only one result and still want to make the server call asynchronously:

```
var user = (await _context.Set<User>().FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.spTest").ToListAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
```