# How to use stored procedures with SqlParameters in EF Core 3.0

Tags: .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

I have tried the below

```
var p = new SqlParameter("Option", "AUTHENTICATE");
var user = _context.Set<User>().FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.spGeneral_Authenticate @Option", p).ToList();
var user = _context.Set<User>().FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.spGeneral_Authenticate @Option=@Option", p).ToList();
```

and

```
SqlParameter[] ps = new SqlParameter[1];
ps[0] = new SqlParameter("Option", "AUTHENTICATE");
var user = _context.Set<User>().FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.spGeneral_Authenticate @Option", ps).ToList();
var user = _context.Set<User>().FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.spGeneral_Authenticate @Option=@Option", ps).ToList();
```

**Error:**

> InvalidCastException: The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null
>   SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects.

Comment: All these seem to work (can't reproduce the exception). Are you using 3.0 release or some older preview bits?

Comment: I am using 3.0 Stable version not preview

Comment: Good. But then why I'm not able to reproduce it? I mean, I have created SP with single parameter and tried all 4 syntaxes from your post and they all worked w/o any problem.

Comment: @IvanStoev It's my mistake i should use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter but i used System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter :)

Comment: Np, it happens :)

Comment: @Palanikumar I was having the same issue before but after using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter` I am having this error `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
Incorrect syntax near ')'.'` . Please suggest.

Comment: @MuhammadAftab, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58167478/1019435

Comment: @Palanikumar I have tried this also but same error.

Comment: Thanks @Palanikumar, It resolved the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> InvalidCastException: The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null
>   SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects.

For the above error, SqlParameter should be [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/) not [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/)

Answer (score 1):

In .Net core 3.0 or above version,Please use below code:
Instead of System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter Use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter

```
 int AuthourId = 3;
 Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter authorId = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@AuthorId", AuthourId);
 IEnumerable<Book> booksByAuthor = shopDbContext.Books
                                                .FromSqlRaw("Select * from Book where AuthorId=@AuthorId", authorId)
                                                .ToList();
```